# Aptana Studio 3 Git Synchronize Workspace function

Tags: eclipse, git, aptana, egit

I have Git installed on my Windows PC.

Normally I use eclipse + egit and dear is a function : "Synchronize Workspace".

How can I get this function in Aptanan Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The native Aptana Git integration doesn't support this function. However, since Aptana is based on Eclipse, you can install EGit in Aptana and with that, you get that function.

Comment: Thx. I did this. But i does not Show the function. Do i need deinstall the installed git plug-in First?